# .htaccess: redirect to https without www results in loop

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, https, no-www

i am trying to redirect my URLs to https. I would like to do the following:

```
http://example.com => https://example.com 
http://www.example.com => https://example.com 
www.example.com => https://example.com 
example.com => https://example.com
```

So convert every URL to https://example.com (With removing the www)!

My current .htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.gif|\.jpg|\.png|\.ogg|\.wav|\.mp3|\.mp4|\.zip|\.pdf|\.fav|\.rar|\.doc)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I have tried to add

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

after and before the first RewriteRule, but it results in an endless loop.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your first rule to this:

```
# remove www and turn on https in same rule
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

And clear your browser cache before testing.

Comment: i dont know why, but it still doesnt work. somehow it results in an endless loop :/

Comment: For testing comment out all other rules and make sure you completely clear browser cache.

Comment: i found the solution and i will add an answer to my question below

Comment: I've update my answer using `%{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto}` as you seem to be behind a proxy. You should still use this single rule for `https` and `www` removal instead of 2 redirect rules (bad for SEO)

Answer (score 0):

i found my solution here:

https://serverfault.com/questions/677560/redirect-loop-when-forcing-https/678402#678402?newreg=f6df6f796eb343a5bbbe1da54c51f93b

```
### Force HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```